# Superposition question (HW help)

Tags: ac, homework, superposition

I'm stuck on this question. I added my attempt to solve it. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

The 2 A current gives -2.848 V and the 5 A current gives 7.121 V. With the AC voltage source I am clueless.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We don't actually "do" homework questions for you, but we can give advice. I assume that you have been asked 3 separate questions, with each of the sources (2 off DC current and an AC voltage) being applied separately.
The following comments apply strictly to the AC case.
After the star > delta transform (correct) it is worth noting that you might as well simplify the circuit further by combining the 45 and 7 ohm resistors in parallel - 315/52. The voltage across the pair will still be the required answer.
You can ignore the 18/11 ohm resistor since it plays no part in determining the voltage across R, being directly across the AC voltage source.
You correctly identify the total impedance of the 27 ohm resistor and the 2 ohm / inductor combination and these are in series with R (now 315/52) across your AC voltage source.  Calculate their total impedance and simplify into real and imaginary parts. Then you can calculate the current through them and hence the voltage across R.
Alternatively you could treat R and the other impedance as an AC voltage divider, but that would involve more complicated and potentially error prone algebra. Better to do it in 2 stages.

Comment: Thank you.
When I use superposition on AC, and I 'cancel' the AC voltage source, should I look at the circuit as a DC circuit? or still look at the inductor phasor?

Comment: @Almog In the 2 DC cases you can assume that it is a "perfect" inductor and has zero impedance. All the other components are "perfect" resistors so it you can treat the circuit as DC. In the AC case you must take into account the inductor as it has a frequency dependent impedance. There is a good article here https://www.tina.com/superposition-in-ac-circuits/. If the question asks for a solution with all 3 sources applied at the same time, Solving for the current sources, the voltage source is replaced by a short circuit and this would be directly across the 2 ( and hence 18/11) ohm resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Your Y-\$\Delta\$ conversion was fine, I suppose. And that's an approach.

Let me lay out the schematic with part numbering, first:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw3bKo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've let the input source off of the schematic. We both know that it is a sine source and you've specified it, already. The above just notes that fact along with a few removals of unnecessary wiring to help clear out the clutter.

Now for some notes about what first crosses my mind:

1. A current source has \$\infty\:\Omega\$ and you have two of them going to the same node. Both either source or sink to a voltage rail. Different ones. But that never matters. They can sink or source to **any** rail and it makes no never-difference. So just remove the two and replace them with one and don't even show the rail it sinks or sources to.
2. \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ across \$R_1\$ has **zero** impact on the rest of the circuit. Remove \$R_1\$ and leave the hole it once filled open.
3. \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ and \$R_2\$ and \$R_4\$ make up a standard voltage divider. So that can be replaced now and the resulting Thevenin resistance of \$\frac{15}{8}\:\Omega\$ (or \$1.875\:\Omega\$) added to \$R_5\$.

Which leaves me with either of the following (left or right side):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWByAL.png)</sup>

That's looking a **lot** simpler, now. (Of course that assumes I was able to read your inductor value as \$4\:\text{mH}\$ about which I'm rather unsure.)